# JavaScript: How to get first parameter, actually first key from URL?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get first key from URL, like this:

```
const currentUrl = window.location.href; 
const parmsFromUrl = new URLSearchParams(currentUrl);
const paramToCheck = parmsFromUrl.keys[0];
```

But constantly I get undefined, can someone tell how me how to get only first parameter, not a value, I just want key? Thanks.

Comment: Guess you meant to use `URL` object, `[...new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.keys()]`

Comment: You want `Array.from(new URLSearchParams(location.search).keys())[0]`. `keys` is a function. It doesn’t have a `0` property. Read the documentation: [`URL`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL), [`URLSearchParams`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Answer (score 4):

> With `URLSearchParams` you have to use `window.location.search`
>
> With `URL` you have to use `window.location.href`

```
const currentUrl = window.location.search;
const parmsFromUrl = new URLSearchParams(currentUrl);
```

`URLSearchParams.keys()` returns an iterator, so you have to use `next()` to get first value

```
const paramToCheck = parmsFromUrl.keys().next().value;
```